# Custom Global filter in PrimeNG (FilterService)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I was facing an issue while filtering the p-table in PrimeNG.
Scenario:

table containing:
John Kelvin Doe

Search key: John Doe

expected: 1 row, I was getting 0 row using built-in filters;

I tried built-in filters, but i was getting 0 records.

I have created a Custom Global Filter that check if input has two words then checking `startsWith` and `endsWith` filters.

```
onGlobalFilter(table: Table, event: Event) {
    table.filterGlobal((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, 'customContains');
}

private configureFilter () {
    // build-in filter
    let containsFilter = this.filterService.filters['contains']; 
    let startsWithFilter = this.filterService.filters['startsWith']; 
    let endsWithFilter = this.filterService.filters['endsWith']; 

    // register  custom filter
    this.filterService.register("customContains", (value, filter): boolean => {
        if (filter === undefined || filter === null || filter.trim() === '') {
            return true;
        }
        if (value === undefined || value === null) {
            return false;
        }
        const str = filter.trim().split(" ");
        if (str.length === 2 ) {
            console.log(filter)

            return startsWithFilter(value, str[0]) &&  endsWithFilter(value, str[1]);
        } else {
            return containsFilter(value, filter); 
        }
    });
}
```

Scenario 2:
search key: john man doe
table entries: john man doe han

Above filter is not working.

I'm looking for a solution which gives correct result for N number of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> John Kelvin Doe

does not contain

> John Doe

It contains John and it contains Doe, but does not contain John Doe. If you want to find entries that contain both words, then you will need to search for contains filter for both and put an && between them.

> john man doe han

starts with

> john man doe

but does not end with

> john man doe

Hence, it's not true that it starts with john man doe AND ends with it. So, instead of your

```
        const str = filter.trim().split(" ");
        if (str.length === 2 ) {
            console.log(filter)

            return startsWithFilter(value, str[0]) &&  endsWithFilter(value, str[1]);
        } else {
            return containsFilter(value, filter); 
        }
```

I recommend

```
        const str = filter.trim().split(" ");
        for (let f of filter) {
            if (!containsFilter(value, f)) return false;
        }
        return true;
```

as the solution. Basically we break up the filter by space and we loop the items and we check for each whether they are contained by `value`.

Comment: Got it, it works for N search key. Thanks

Comment: @Shrip happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matches latest PrimeNG Table.

```
<p-table
 ...
 [globalFilterFields]="['column_name']">

  <button (click)="table.filterGlobal(['ValueOne', 'ValueTwo'], 'in')"></button>
  <button (click)="table.filterGlobal('ValueOne', 'contains')"></button>
```

The key is the "constraint" `in` and `contains`. See the other [filter service constraints](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/filterservice#builtinconstraints)